# Load html file from a local war folder

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a web app, all its resources are contained in a folder named "war".I've imported these into my xcode project (via File -> "Add Files to 'my project'").

Now my xcode project looks like:

```
MyProject
    |- war
        |- foo.html
    |- AppDelegate.h
    |- AppDelegate.m
    ...
```

so now I try loading like:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[bundle pathForResource:@"foo" ofType:@"html"] isDirectory:NO];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.mWebView loadRequest:req];
```

I don't get compile errors, but my UIWebView is empty. I do get webViewDidLoad callbacks too. Is there some other way we need to load local pages like this?

Thanks

Comment: If you preserved the directory names, use [URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:). If the folders were converted to to groups within the project, then you just use [URLForResource:withExtension:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/URLForResource:withExtension:).

Comment: Hi, I think the dir names were preserved, haven't modified anything. For some reason, xcode complains about the first method you listed, says it's not found. I can get the "URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:inBundleWithURL:" one to compile, but I'm not sure what to use for "inBundleWithURL". Shouldn't the one you listed compile ok? It says 10.6 and above...

Comment: `NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" withExtension:@"html" subdirectory:@"war"];` works fine for me.

Comment: See my answer. By the way, my links above were accidentally the OS X versions, but my answer has the iOS links, which clearly show these methods are good in iOS 4 or later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's a true subdirectory (i.e., the folder name shows up in blue):

[image]

Then you can use [`URLForResource:withExtension:subdirectory:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-SW8):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" 
                                     withExtension:@"html"
                                      subdirectory:@"war"];
```

Alternatively, if it's simply a "group" (i.e. if the "folder" doesn't show up in blue):

[image]

Then you use the plain old [`URLForResource:withExtension:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-SW9):

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"foo" 
                                     withExtension:@"html"];
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I had an embarrassingly hard time getting this to work. I had to add the files with the "Create folder references for any added folders" option. Then I used the 1st method you listed above. Importing the files with the "Create groups for any added folders" just didn't seem to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is how I usually load local html files without a problem.

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:self.fileName withExtension:nil]]]
```

Since your code mostly looks right to me I think it may be some other problem. I suggest setting up a delegate for your webView and checking its `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` method to see if that gives more information.

Also make sure your `foo.html` is a target member.